# read.csv / read_csv dropping values

Tags: r

I'm reading in a .csv with a geographic data column, `Geo Shape`. It has geojson, a json representation of geographic data. For some reason, both read_csv and read.csv are dropping values in the `Geo Shape` column. I'm using `;` as the separator.

Data I'm using is here. (I tried both the csv and excel files):
https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/zillow-neighborhoods/export/

If you open the csv in a spreadsheet program, you can see all of the `Geo Shape` values are  populated. But when you load it into a data.frame, some of the values drop. Any insight into why this is happening and what can be done to fix?

Comment: I think i figured it out. There actually is data in the Geo Shape column when I access it in the console, but R Studio isn't printing in the View mode. Maybe this is just a bug because the string is so long it doesn't get displayed in the View mode.

Comment: If you download the Geojson file you can read that directly into a spatial object using `sf::st_read()`